# Ruby feed parsing: "Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding!"

Tags: ruby, feedzirra

I am trying to parse RSS feeds using [Feedzirra](https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra).

Some of them are ok, but others return the error:

> Error while parsing. Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not seem to be a Feedzirra issue, IMO.
Your libxml or nokigiri dependencies may not be up-to-date. Update these gems and try again.

Like [mentioned here](http://nokogiri.org/), encoding detection is not 100% accurate.

If you'd like to ignore the ones which give you errors,
Feedzirra has callback functions

> Another feature present in Feedzirra is the ability to create callback
>   functions that get called “on success” and “on failure” when getting a
>   feed. This makes it easy to do things like log errors or update data
>   stores.

Also, please give us more context on what code gives you the error or which file are you trying to parse.

Comment: Nokogiri Encoding docs: http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html#encoding